# When uploading a file on Google Forms, I would like the file uploads to go into a custom folder based on the form response (their name)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Ex. someone submitting the form with a file upload and on form submit it creates a custom folder based on their form response (their name) on Google Drive with their submission in it.

Using this script, I can put all files into one folder, but I don't know enough about script to know where to change what the folder is named

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "<<Folder ID here>>";

const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter(
        (itemResponse) =>
          itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
      )
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      const subfolderName = response.getId();
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: This is the line where the folder is named `const subfolderName = response.getId();` If you need further help, please add more details regarding how you collect "their name" i.e. what is the question that asks for their name.

Answer (score 1):

You are using (verbatim) the script from the article by [Digital Inspiration](https://www.labnol.org/) called [How to Move Files Uploads from Google Forms to a Specific Folder in Google Drive](https://www.labnol.org/file-uploads-folder-google-forms-201226). The nature of your question suggests that you have little or no experience with Apps Script; if this is so, then I suggest that you begin by reading [developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).

Regarding your question, there are two instructions relating to assigning the folder into which uploads will be saved:

- `Create Parent Folder: To get started, go to your Google Drive and create a new folder (or use an existing folder). Open the folder and grab the ID of the folder from the browser’s address bar as shown in the screenshot.`
- `Remember to replace the Folder Id in line #1 with the Id of the folder that you’ve created in the previous step.`

Uploads for each unique response are saved to a custom folder within the parent folder. To quote the article: *The name of the custom folder is the unique Response Id that Google Forms automatically assigns to every form submission.*